# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list' for plotting program

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am getting the following error for the code below in line 11(where b is defined):

unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

```
#Needed libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

#Defining given complex refractive indices 
N1=complex(1.5,-7.6)
N2=complex(1.0,0.0)

#Defining the function that gives physically reasonable answer for effective medium
def B(x):
    a=-2
    b=(N1**2)*(2*(1-x)-x)+(N2**2)*(2*x-(1-x))
    c=(N1**2)*(N2**2)
    Nsq = (-b + np.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
    return np.sqrt(Nsq)

#Plotting the function
G=B(n)
mpl.plot(n,G)
mpl.show()
```

Could someone help me out? I'm not sure where the problem is and I'm not too experienced with scientific python usage. Thanks!

Comment: where is `n` defined? The code is not complete. I bet that `n` is a list which makes formula to compute b invalid (mix of int & list)

Comment: n in the code represents a volume fraction, so I want it to take all values between 0 and 1. However when I say something like float n = range(0,1) it says invalid syntax.

Comment: all values between 0 and 1 ?? well that's infinite!!! and `range` only works on integers. Show us how you define `n`.

Comment: I wish to make n a continuous variable that ranges from 0 to 1. I'm not entirely sure how to put this in python language. I initially made tried it using the range function with a small step size but the error that I mentioned still did not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code to:

- define a range of floats between 0 and 1
- call `B` on each value and compose an array

code:

```
#Needed libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

#Defining given complex refractive indices
N1=complex(1.5,-7.6)
N2=complex(1.0,0.0)

#Defining the function that gives physically reasonable answer for effective medium
def B(x):
    a=-2
    b=(N1**2)*(2*(1-x)-x)+(N2**2)*(2*x-(1-x))
    c=(N1**2)*(N2**2)
    Nsq = (-b + np.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
    return np.sqrt(Nsq)

nb_values = 10  # you can set it higher
n = np.linspace(0,1,nb_values+1)
# returns array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ])

#calling the function for each x in n, build an array from results
G=[B(x) for x in n]
#Plotting the function
mpl.plot(n,G)
mpl.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there however a way to let n be continuous? Or does that simply mean making the step size really small in the np.linspace function?

Comment: "let n be continuous" is possible in a pure mathematics point of view but not in computers: infinite values mean infinite computation time even if it was possible... You have to reduce the step until you're satifsied with the plotted graphics.